# How do I give a container a preferred height that can later be changed?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

This is my `Container`:

```
Container(
       height: height - height * 0.4, //this is my preferred height.
       width: width - width * 0.7,
       decoration: decoration,
       child: Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25.0),
           child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  'assets/opensource.png',
                  scale: 1.35,
                ),
              text('Open Source Software', 20, Color(0xFF02bbe5)),
              text('Contributor since December, 2020', 16,
                   Color(0xFF02bbe5)),
              Padding(
                 padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                 child: text(
                    'test',
                     16,
                     Colors.blueGrey),
              ),
           ],
        ),
     ),
),
```

I need to make the app responsive, for that the `Container` needs to be elongated when the inner widgets don't fit inside the `Container` properly.

How do I give a preferred height to this `Container` but also allow it to resize freely in case of overflow?

Note: This `Container` is inside a `Column` itself with `SingleChildScrollView` as the parent. And I am building a `web` app.

Edit: I have used MediaQuery for getting width and height.

Comment: Are you using MediaQuery to get the height and Width?

Comment: yes I have used MediaQuery @Mudassir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to approach this problem. You can wrap you container inside an `AspectRatio` widget and an Expanded.

```
AspectRatio(
   aspectRatio: someAspectRatioValue,
   child: Expanded(
       child Container(...)
   )
)
```

This should expand the items container without loosing shape of the container.

You can also build your whole screen with a [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html), though that would require a lot of reworking.

Comment: Thanks! I settled on using the `LayoutBuilder` at last.

Comment: Please the mark the answer as correct.

Thank you

Comment: As of now this is the answer. But this was not the exact solution I was looking for. I was looking for something simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your application responsive in Flutter then you should `Sizer` package( [Here](https://pub.dev/packages/sizer) ). This package will make your app responsive for any screen size, it divides into percentages. For ex:

```
Container(
  width: 20.w,    //It will take a 20% of screen width
  height:30.h     //It will take a 30% of screen height
)
```

Comment: I was not looking for any 3rd party package.